# Alternative to WndProc because needed in Class derived from Component?

Tags: c#, winforms, components

I am writing a custom control derived from Component.

In this control I need to be able somehow to get OS messages WM_DEVICEDCHANGED to create some events from.

Usually I would just override WndProc directly in the applications Form, but it is really important that this functionallity lays directly in the control instead.

Even though the control will always be used on a Form it is important that the OS messages are received on the control that is derived from Component so when dropping the control on a form there is no need to add functionality for it manually IN the form.

I have seen some examples mentioning NativeWindow and other solutions, but I have not been able to find head or tail in any of it, so I hope someone here can help me out.

Thanks...

Comment: You'll need to be more specific, it is completely unclear whether subclassing the host form could work or a separate window needs to be created.  Document what you want to accomplish and at least mention the messages you want to receive.

Comment: Sorry. I thought that I already wrote that i want to receive the WM_DEVICECHANGED message. I want to receive the message in my component rather than in the form the component is used on. Without using WndProc on the form.

Comment: I might not explain it too well, but basicly I want to be able to do in my Component what WndProc does in a form class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to receive the WM_DEVICECHANGED message

Okay, that just requires subclassing the window of the form on which you drop the component.  Any top-level window gets that message.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Build.  Drop the new component from the top of the toolbox onto a form.  Add an event handler for the DeviceChange event and add any code that's relevant to the kind of device change notification that you are interested in.  You could also put that code in the OnDeviceChange() method to further specialize the notification and raise more specific events.  It is up to you to take it from here.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class DeviceChangeNotifier : Component {
    public delegate void DeviceChangeDelegate(Message msg);
    public event DeviceChangeDelegate DeviceChange;

    public DeviceChangeNotifier() {
        // Add initialization here
    }
    public DeviceChangeNotifier(IContainer container) : this() {
        // In case you need automatic disposal
        container.Add(this);
    }
    public DeviceChangeNotifier(ContainerControl parentControl) : this() {
        // In case you want to use it without the designer            
        this.ContainerControl = parentControl;
    }

    public ContainerControl ContainerControl {
        // References the parent form
        get { return this.parentControl; }
        set { 
            this.parentControl = value;
            this.parentControl.HandleCreated += parentControl_HandleCreated;
        }
    }

    private void parentControl_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Subclass the form when its handle is created
        snooper = new MessageSnooper(this, parentControl.Handle);        
    }

    protected void OnDeviceChange(Message msg) {
        // Raise the DeviceChange message
        var handler = DeviceChange;
        if (handler != null) handler(msg);
    }

    public override ISite Site {
        // Runs at design time, ensures designer initializes ContainerControl 
        // so we'll have a reference to the parent form without it having to do any work
        set { 
            base.Site = value;
            if (value == null) return;
            IDesignerHost service = value.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
            if (service == null) return;
            IComponent rootComponent = service.RootComponent;
            this.ContainerControl = rootComponent as ContainerControl;
        }
    }

    private ContainerControl parentControl;
    private MessageSnooper snooper;
    private const int WM_DESTROY = 0x0002;
    private const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;

    private class MessageSnooper : NativeWindow {
        // Subclasses the parent window
        public MessageSnooper(DeviceChangeNotifier owner, IntPtr handle) {
            this.owner = owner;
            this.AssignHandle(handle);
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            if (m.Msg == WM_DESTROY) this.ReleaseHandle();
            if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE) owner.OnDeviceChange(m);
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        private DeviceChangeNotifier owner;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. It creates a new component ofcourse, but I think I am able to integrate it into my own without help. :)

Comment: Alternatively, you might be able to go down the nasty road of pinvoke to CreateWindow with the msgwindow style (don't recall actual value), which should also give you a message pump...

Comment: @JerKimball thanks but I got Hans's solution working. Ony thing that is a little annoying is that the ContainerControl appears as a public property. No way to get around that?

Comment: OK forget my last question. I am a zombie those days...[Browsable(false)] is the answer ofcourse :)